# Java ZK+Javascript JQuery Galleria IO FullScreenMode

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, zk, galleria

i am using `Galleria` plugin for JavaScript i need show the image in `full Screen mode`i have checked the `API`and have a method.

```
.enterFullscreen( [callback] )
returns Galleria
This will set the gallery in fullscreen mode. It will temporary manipulate some document  styles and blow up the gallery to cover the browser screen. Note that it will only fill the browser window, not the client screen (javascript can’t do that).
```

[API](http://galleria.io/docs/api/methods/#enterfullscreen-callback)

i am using `ZK Framework` responding to a button click using this code.

```
public void imageZoomer()
{
        Clients.evalJavaScript("$('#galleria').data('galleria').enterFullscreen(function() {alert('full screen mode');})");     
}
```

but nothing happens i have also try using

```
Clients.evalJavaScript("imageZoomer()");
```

and a `javascript` function like this

```
function imageZoomer()
{
alert('before');
$('#galleria').data('galleria').enterFullscreen(function(){alert('full screen mode');})
alert('after');
}
```

the above function is called but nothing happens but if a try this code on firebug console

```
$('#galleria').data('galleria').enterFullscreen(function(){alert('full screen mode');})
```

it works smoothly what i am doing wrong thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

finally i could solved my issue using a `xmhtml` button in ZK and responding `onClick` event using JQuery i couldn't solve my issue using `ZK button` here is my code i hope i really helps somebody.

```
<div xmlns:h="xhtml">
   <h:button onclick="$('#galleria').data('galleria').toggleFullscreen();">Full Screen.          </h:button>
</div>
```

best regards..